# Can't get fillbetween in a pgfplot to work for me

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I try to fill an area between two plots in pgfplot diagram in a specific domain using the pgfplotslibrary fillbetween but I can't manage to get a result.

Maybe one of you could say what am I doing wrong in my code?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=newest,tick label style={font=\sffamily},
    xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tick}},
    yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tick}},
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{backgound,main,foregound}

\usetikzlibrary{%
    backgrounds, 
    arrows,
    spy, 
    backgrounds, 
    external, 
    plotmarks
}

\begin{filecontents*}{minmax1.csv}
x1  ; x2    ; x3    ; x4    ; x5    ; x6   ; x7  ; x8  ; x9   ; x10
4,5 ; 0,33  ; 0,36  ; 0,33  ; 0,36  ; 0,36 ; 0,4 ; 1   ; 0,34 ; 0,35
4,8 ; 0,34  ; 0,38  ; 0,34  ; 0,375 ; 0,36 ; 0,4 ; 1   ; 0,34 ; 0,37
5   ; 0,35  ; 0,385 ; 0,35  ; 0,385 ; 0,36 ; 0,4 ; 0,5 ; 0,34 ; 0,38
5,2 ; 0,37  ; 0,4   ; 0,37  ; 0,4   ; 0,36 ; 0,4 ; 0   ; 0,34 ; 0,39
5,5 ; 0,375 ; 0,41  ; 0,375 ; 0,41  ; 0,36 ; 0,4 ; 0   ; 0,34 ; 0,41
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}{}
    \begin{overprint}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                cycle list={%
                    {DarkGreen,solid, thick},
                    {DarkBlue,solid, thick},
                    {gray!50,solid, thin},
                    {red,dashed,thin},
                    {red,dashed,thin},
                    {red,dashed,thin},
                },
                font={\sffamily},
                every axis label/.append style={font=\sffamily\footnotesize},
                width=\textwidth,%Breite des Plots
                axis line style=thin,%Achsenstärke
                axis line style={gray!30},
                axis y line = center,
                axis x line = center,
                tick label style={font={\sansmath\sffamily\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont}},
                x label style={at={(axis description cs:1.0,-0.03)},anchor=north, font={\tiny}},
                y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.08,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south, font={\tiny}},
                every y tick/.style={gray!30},
                ytick={0.3,0.31,...,0.5},
                extra y ticks = {0.31,0,32,...,0.5},
                extra y tick labels= \empty, 
                every x tick/.style={gray!30},
                xtick={0,0.1,...,5.5},
                extra x ticks = {0,0.1,...,15},
                extra x tick labels= \empty, 
                no markers,%keine Markierungen auf den Plots
                every axis plot/.append style={thin},%Plotstärke
                every axis/.append style={font=\sffamily},%Plotstärke
                axis on top=false,%Achsen hinter dem Plot
                font={\sffamily},
            ]
        %%Plots
            \addplot table[col sep=semicolon,/pgf/number format/read comma as period, x index = {0}, y index = {2}]{minmax1.csv};
            \addplot table[name path=F, col sep=semicolon,/pgf/number format/read comma as period, x index = {0}, y index = {3}]{minmax1.csv};
            \addplot table[col sep=semicolon,/pgf/number format/read comma as period, x index = {0}, y index = {9}]{minmax1.csv};
            \addplot table[name path=G, col sep=semicolon,/pgf/number format/read comma as period, x index = {0}, y index = {5}]{minmax1.csv};
            \addplot table[col sep=semicolon,/pgf/number format/read comma as period, x index = {0}, y index = {6}]{minmax1.csv};
%This is what does not work:
%\addplot[fill, color=brown!50]fill between[of=F and G, soft clip={domain=4.9:5.1}];

        %This is for the blue lines in the background
                \scoped[on background layer]\draw[color=blue, dotted] (axis cs:5.0,0.33) -- (axis cs:5.0,0.41);
                \scoped[on background layer]\draw[color=blue!50, dotted] (axis cs:4.8,0.33) -- (axis cs:4.8,0.41);
                \scoped[on background layer]\draw[color=blue!50, dotted] (axis cs:5.2,0.33) -- (axis cs:5.2,0.41);


        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And this is what I actually try to achieve:

[image]

I would also like to mark an area with a text centered and arrows pointing to the edge of that area. Does anyone have a hint how to do that?

Comment: You've done the classical mistake of adding plot options to the table. `\addplot[name path=F] table[...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I had a bit of trouble getting your example to run at all. I had to change the commas to periods in the datafile, and remove the extra ticks (which were pointless anyway) to avoid a dimension too large error. Hence the code has changed a bit.)

Your mistake is likely the fact that you've added `name path` as an option to `table`, and not `\addplot`. As a result, the paths weren't actually named, and the `fill between` didn't work. You need

```
\addplot [name path=F] table[x index=...]
```

and not

```
\addplot table[name path=F,x index=...]
```

As for the arrow you wanted, you can just do something like

```
\draw [Stealth-Stealth] (4.8,0.335) --node[fill=white,align=center,font=\tiny]{Something\\like this} (5.2,0.335);
```

just before `\end{axis}`.

The `Stealth` arrow tip comes from the newer `arrows.meta` library. The old `arrows` library that you load is considered deprecated. That I don't use `axis cs` in the coordinates comes from the fact that with `compat=1.11` or newer, `axis cs` is default for coordinates in an `axis`, so you don't need to specify it explicitly.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[xcolor={svgnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.15, %better to use explicit number
    tick label style={font=\sffamily},
    xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tick}},
    yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber[assume math mode=true]{\tick}},
}


\usetikzlibrary{%
    arrows.meta, %arrows is deprecated
%    spy, 
    backgrounds,
    external, 
%    plotmarks
}


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{minmax1.csv}
x1  ; x2    ; x3    ; x4    ; x5    ; x6   ; x7  ; x8  ; x9   ; x10
4.5 ; 0.33  ; 0.36  ; 0.33  ; 0.36  ; 0.36 ; 0.4 ; 1   ; 0.34 ; 0.35
4.8 ; 0.34  ; 0.38  ; 0.34  ; 0.375 ; 0.36 ; 0.4 ; 1   ; 0.34 ; 0.37
5   ; 0.35  ; 0.385 ; 0.35  ; 0.385 ; 0.36 ; 0.4 ; 0.5 ; 0.34 ; 0.38
5.2 ; 0.37  ; 0.4   ; 0.37  ; 0.4   ; 0.36 ; 0.4 ; 0   ; 0.34 ; 0.39
5.5 ; 0.375 ; 0.41  ; 0.375 ; 0.41  ; 0.36 ; 0.4 ; 0   ; 0.34 ; 0.41
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                cycle list={%
                    {DarkGreen,solid, thick},
                    {DarkBlue,solid, thick},
                    {gray!50,solid, thin},
                    {red,dashed,thin},
                    {red,dashed,thin},
                    {red,dashed,thin},
                },
                font={\sffamily},
                every axis label/.append style={font=\sffamily\footnotesize},
                width=\textwidth,%Breite des Plots
                axis line style=thin,%Achsenstärke
                axis line style={gray!30},
                axis y line = center,
                axis x line = center,
                tick label style={font={\sansmath\sffamily\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont}},
                x label style={at={(axis description cs:1.0,-0.03)},anchor=north, font={\tiny}},
                y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.08,.5)},rotate=90,anchor=south, font={\tiny}},
                every y tick/.style={gray!30},
                ytick={0.3,0.31,...,0.5},
                xtick={0,0.1,...,5.5},
                no markers,%keine Markierungen auf den Plots
                every axis plot/.append style={thin},%Plotstärke
                every axis/.append style={font=\sffamily},%Plotstärke
                axis on top=false,%Achsen hinter dem Plot
                font={\sffamily},
            ]

        %%Plots
            \addplot table[col sep=semicolon, x index = {0}, y index = {2}]{minmax1.csv};
            \addplot[name path=F] table[col sep=semicolon, x index = {0}, y index = {3}]{minmax1.csv};
            \addplot table[col sep=semicolon, x index = {0}, y index = {9}]{minmax1.csv};
            \addplot[name path=G] table[col sep=semicolon, x index = {0}, y index = {5}]{minmax1.csv};
            \addplot table[col sep=semicolon, x index = {0}, y index = {6}]{minmax1.csv};


\addplot [color=brown!50] fill between[of=F and G,soft clip={domain=4.9:5.1}];


        %This is for the blue lines in the background
\begin{scope}%[on background layer] %didn't work, don't know why
  \draw[color=blue, dotted] (axis cs:5.0,0.33) -- (axis cs:5.0,0.41);
  \draw[color=blue!50, dotted] (axis cs:4.8,0.33) -- (axis cs:4.8,0.41);
  \draw[color=blue!50, dotted] (axis cs:5.2,0.33) -- (axis cs:5.2,0.41);
\end{scope}

\draw [Stealth-Stealth] (4.8,0.335) --node[fill=white,align=center,font=\tiny]{Something\\like this} (5.2,0.335);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I wonder why you've had trouble with the commas, since this ran fine on my system.

Comment: @schmendrich I think I just messed something up, it worked fine now I tried again. (Forgot to mention by the way, you have a couple of typos in your `\pgfsetlayers`.)